# Membership provider error mvc web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I am getting membership error in my application.

This is my `web.config` section that is creating error.

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

Like all other same questions like this one I have read, are telling me about adding `defaultProvider` and `name` to this config file.

But I already have `defaultProvider` and name set to by default in there.

What other customization needs to be done?

You can see this error here-

http://funranger.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there is already a membership provider registered  before your configuration file is loaded.

You'll need to remove the first membership provider, and this can be done by clearing all providers before you add one, just as you are doing with your connectionstrings.

In the  configuration section, inside the membership/providers section, add a  element before the  element(s).

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="WorkI" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

And also add the below line in your web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=YourServername;Initial Catalog=YourDBname;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You were right, I was missing `DefaultConnection` in connectionStrings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your membership provider's declaration should look like in the web.config under the system.web element

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add 
          name="SqlProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
          applicationName="MyApplication"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```